# I selected "curve A" as the bevel object of "curve B", but changing the scale of curve A from geometry nodes doesn't affect the scale of curve B

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry, geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

These are the objects involved:

[image]

I have set the BezierCircle curve as the bevel object for the Plane.001 curve.

[image]

This is the node setup for the BezierCircle curve:

[image]

The nodes were meant to scale the BezierCircle curve if the camera is within a 4.5m radius of the Plane.001 curve.

The BezierCircle curve is being scaled as intended:

[image]

***BUT***, the scaling of the BezierCircle curve doesn't affect the Plane.001 curve at all:

[image]

It scales properly when done from the transform panel or in edit mode, but not from the geometry nodes. I don't undertand why this happens.

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the geometry via a *Bevel Object* is always done before any manipulation by *Geometry Nodes*.

Therefore, if the *Bevel Object* is changed by *Geometry Nodes*, no change will be visible.

At the moment, the only solution is to extrude using the `Curve to Mesh` node in *Geometry Nodes* as well:

[image]

By the way, you get better control over the area of effect with the node `Map Range`.